# does 心 used for translation of the heart as an organ?

Tags: meaning-in-context, simplified-characters

I would like to know which Chinese word is used when we are speaking about the heart as an organ, and not a feeling or the seat of soul affections. The most commonly used word :-)

Comment: Yes, period. Or 心臟/心脏, more specifically.

Answer (score 4):

When referring to the organ in a medical setting, it'll often be the longer, more precise form [心脏](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BF%83%E8%84%8F), e.g.:

> 他父亲刚从**心脏**手术中恢复过来。
> His father has just recovered from **heart** surgery.

By your description, it looks like you would want to use this longer form.

When used more casually, it'll often be the shorter form [心](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BF%83), e.g.:

> 他看见她时，**心**猛地一跳。
> His **heart** gave a sudden leap when he saw her.

This still literally describes his heart jumping, but it could also be used figuratively.  Then it gets a bit more metaphorical with e.g.:

> 她有一颗善良的**心**。
> She has a kind **heart**.

It is also often used metaphorically in the construct [心里](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BF%83%E9%87%8C) to indicate personal feelings, e.g.:

> 看到他们这样确实让我**心里**难过。
> It really breaks my **heart** to see them this way.

Comment: The second example could be understand as 心 used in the word 心跳. When composing a longer word with the organ heart, it typically use 心 in the word. For example: 心房、心室、心肌、心率、心律、心衰、心绞痛、心动过速……